# A calculation in two depth association

Tags: associations

I have a dataset where values are associations too.

```
 dataset=<| 2 -> <|3 -> 3, 5 -> 4|>,4 -> <|5 -> 15|>, 5 -> <|1 -> 41, 2 -> 4, 
 3 -> 10, 4 -> 11|>|>
```

I am interested in calculating a value of each value by multiplying all values except its value. For example, the value of `dataset[5, 3]` will be `dataset[5, 3] = 41 * 3 * 11`. I calculate this in the following manner

```
 Times @@ Values[dataset[[Key[5]]]]/dataset[5, 3]
```

Any suggestion how to speed up the calculation?

Comment: `multiply[m_, n_] := Times @@ Drop[dataset[m], {n}]` ?

Comment: This does it for all keys at first level at once and build an according association: `Map[
 a \[Function] 
  Association@KeyValueMap[#1 -> Times @@ KeyDrop[a, #1] &, a],
 dataset
 ]`.

Comment: `Query[Key@5,Times@@KeyDrop[#,3]&]@dataset`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
map[f_, m_, n_]:= Query[Key @ m, f @@ KeyDrop[n] @ #&]

map[Times, 5, 3] @ dataset
```

> 1804

```
map[Plus, 5, 3] @ dataset
```

> 56